# Como manejar muchas variables en Dialogflow

Tags: php

estoy desarrollando un chatbot en Dialogflow el cual se conforma de 40 preguntas (y por ende 40 respuestas), cada una de las respuestas las estoy guardando en una variable distinta y de ahi las mando a mi webhook. El problema con el que me encuentro es que dialogflow solo permite 20 variables en 1 intent y no se como hacer para poder mandar todas las variables (respuestas) directamente a mi webhook. Si a alguien se le ocurre alguna solución estaría bueno que la comparta.

Gracias y Saludos!